# Prove that $\pi$ is in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How can I prove that the number $\pi$ exist or that it's real?

I know how to prove the existence of $\sqrt{2}$ and I know how to prove that $\pi$ cannot be a rational number but how do we prove that it's even exist?

Comment: What's your definition of $\pi$? (Also, how is this related do discrete-mathematics?)

Comment: You want to prove the existance of pi algebraically or geometrically ?

Comment: I can't believe you know how to prove $\pi$ isn't rational, but not how to prove it exists.

Comment: An off topic suggestion: to write mathematical expressions you can write them between "\$\$", so they look better. For instance, \$\pi\$ looks like this: $\pi$. This is of course far from obligatory, but it will make your posts more readable.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi), $\pi$ exists and is real (with respect to all common definitions).

Answer (score 6):

Geometrically we may define 
$$
\pi := 2\int_{x=-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^{2}},
$$
the area of the unit circle of center $(0,0)$ and radius $1$; then $\pi$ is real.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Define $\displaystyle C(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$
2. Prove that the series converges uniformly on compact sets so that $C(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$
3. Show that $C(0) = 1$ and $C(2) < 0$.
4. Deduce that $P = \inf \{ t > 0 \mid C(t) = 0\}$ exists and that $P > 0$
5. Define $\pi = 2P$. Voila.

Comment: This is a very nice proof. But I am not sure the asker is familiar with analytical notions like continuous functions, convergent series or compact sets.